# Conditionally LIMIT in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, conditional-statements, limit

I have read that in Postgres setting `LIMIT NULL` will effectively not limit the results of the `SELECT`. However in BigQuery when I set `LIMIT NULL` based on a condition I see `Syntax error: Unexpected keyword NULL`.

I'd like to figure out a way to limit or not based on a condition (could be an argument passed into a procedure, or a parameter passed in by a query job, anything I can write a `CASE` or `IF` statement for). The mechanism for setting the condition shouldn't matter, what I'm looking for is whether there is a way to syntactically indicate a value for `LIMIT`, that will not limit, in a valid way to BigQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LIMIT` clause works differently within BigQuery. It specifies the maximum number of depression inputs in the result. The `LIMIT` n must be a constant INT64.

Using the `LIMIT` clause, you can overcome the limitation on cache result size:

- Using filters to limit the result set.
- Using a LIMIT clause to reduce the result set, especially if you are
  using an ORDER BY clause.

You can see this example:

```
SELECT
  title
FROM
  `my-project.mydataset.mytable`
ORDER BY
  title DESC
LIMIT
  100
```

This will only return 100 rows.

The best practice is to use it if you are sorting a very large number of values. You can see this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-output#use_a_limit_clause_with_large_sorts) with examples.

If you want to return all rows from a table, you need to omit the LIMIT clause.

```
SELECT
  title
FROM
  `my-project.mydataset.mytable`
ORDER BY
  title DESC
```

This example will return all the rows from a table. It is not recommended to omit `LIMIT` if your tables are too large, as it will consume a lot of resources.

One solution to optimize resources is to use cluster tables. This will save costs and querying times. You can see this [document](https://hoffa.medium.com/bigquery-optimized-cluster-your-tables-65e2f684594b) with a detailed explanation of how it works.

Comment: “ If you want to return all rows from a table, you need to omit the LIMIT clause.” thanks for definitively stating that. I’m thinking about my problem in another way now.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a stored procedure that dynamically creates a query based on input parameters. Once your sql query is ready, you can use execute immediate to run that. In this way, you can control what value should be provided to the limit clause of your query.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate

Hope this answers your query.